# How to Retrieve text value when using ng-repeat with (key,value) syntax

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

This is regarding AngularJS ng-repeat . I have the following HTML code

```html
<div class="selections">
  <select class="form-control" size="15" data-ng-model="selections[$index]">

    <option data-ng-repeat="(key,value) in elements" 
            data-ng-bind-html="value | add_space" value="{{key}}">value</option>

  </select>
  
  <p>List of Selections : {{selections[$index]}}</p>


</div>
```

Currently I am able to get the value using `ng-model="selections[$index]"`. 
How do I retrieve the text using the same format?

I am restricted to use the `[$index]` format as my entire code block is within another **ng-repeat** loop.

Thanks in advance

Comment: try use `ng-options` instead of `ng-repeat`.  `ng-options =  key as value for (key,value) in elements`

Comment: @SSH How would I retrieve the value using ng-model then?
Do i use the same syntax of selections[$index] ??

Comment: I tried. it does not render any option list.

Comment: can you share more data or create plunker?